# in BST i am coping a node into another node and deleting the first node and returning the copied node but the copied node values are garbage

Tags: visual-c++

ok so in c++ BST I am trying to delete a node and return the values in the node. what I am doing is setting x node = node to be deleted. so when I delete the node and return x and display its values it has some garbage values in it.

```
BSTNode* x=n;

x->set_id(n->get_id());

x->set_price(n->get_price());

x->set_quantity(n->get_quantity());

BSTNode* temp = find_prev(n, root);

if (n->get_id() <= root->get_id())
{

  temp->set_left(n->get_left());

}

else if (n->get_id() >= root->get_id())
{

  temp->set_right(n->get_right());

}

delete n;

return x;
```

I expect the ouput to be some value , but its showing garbage values.

Comment: x has values before the deletion of n and after deletion of n the x becomes garbage. can anyone tell me how to solve this so that x dont become garbage

Comment: How was `x` declared and initialized? What is it pointing to? Show a [mcve]

Comment: x is a node which I set equal to another node n. Example BSTNode* x=n; but it alone was not working so tried to set x node data step by step equal to n node data.

Comment: Well I have solved this problem by storing the n node data in variables and making a new node based on that variables but I dont like this because if we had a lot of data in node it will be annoying to set each variable to the data of n node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BSTNode* x=n;` does not create a new node. It declares a new pointer pointing to the same node. `x->set_id(n->get_id());` then does absolutely nothing - it reads a value from the node, and puts it right back into that same node, which of course already has that value.

Moreover, after `delete n;`, `x` becomes a dangling pointer, pointing to a node that has already been deleted. Any attempt to use `x` afterwards exhibits undefined behavior.

If you want to create a new node with the same data as the original, you likely want `BSTNode* x = new BSTNode(*n);`. Assuming `BSTNode` has a suitable copy constructor.

---

However, the point of that exercise is unclear. Why again do you want to create a new node, copy data over, and delete the original? It seems rather pointless - at the end, you are right were you started, with a single node carrying certain data. Why can't you just continue using the original node?

Comment: I am trying to copy the data to another node because I am making this function in such a way that it returns the values of node it had deleted. So when the original node is deleted we can get a confirmation that it was the node that we intended to delete.

Comment: Just detach the node from the list, and return it. It has the same net effect.

Comment: detaching the node does not free up space. we just have a node covering space in memory.

Comment: You want to return a node to the caller - that node would have to take up space. Whether you create a new node then delete the old one, or just keep the old one around, you use one node's worth of memory in the end.